# SPARQL not returning correct response

Tags: ruby, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to fetch a few records via dbpedia using following sparql:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ?thing, ?url, ?genre WHERE {
      ?thing foaf:name             ?name ;
             foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .
      ?name  bif:contains "'mega'" .
      {
        ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
               a                 dbpedia-owl:Band
      }
      UNION
      {
        ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
               a                 dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist
      }
      UNION
      {
        ?thing a <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/MusicalPerformer>
      }
    }
    LIMIT 1000
```

It works correctly most of the times unless I try to search for "James brown" instead of "mega" then I don't get any results, however when I just search for James I get James brown as one of the result items.

Give it a try to this queries using the [DBpedia's SPARQL Query Editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Please help me debug why I am not getting the correct results when I enter "James brown" as the query string.

Comment: Are you entering "James brown" with a lower-case b or "James Brown" with a capital B ?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that http://dbpedia.org/resource/James_Brown has as the value of foaf:name "Brown, James Joseph, Jr.", so "James Brown" won't match.  I'd write the query using the standard **contains** filter function and ask for both names individually:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing, ?url, ?genre WHERE {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Band dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/MusicalPerformer> }
  ?thing foaf:name ?name ;
         foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url ;
         a ?type .
  optional { ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre } 
  filter contains( str(?name), "James" )
  filter contains( str(?name), "Brown" )
}
LIMIT 1000
```

That gets three results, all referring to James Brown, the Godfather of Soul.  Another option would be to use the rdfs:label property, which *would* contain James Brown (it contains the Wikipedia article name):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing, ?url, ?genre WHERE {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Band dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/MusicalPerformer> }
  ?thing rdfs:label?name ;
         foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url ;
         a ?type .
  optional { ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre } 
  filter contains( str(?name), "James Brown" )
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Your second query works quite well, is there a way to make it case insensitive? thanks for your answer by the way :)

Comment: To do a case insensitive search, I'd do, e.g., `filter contains( lcase(str(?name)), lcase("James Brown"))`.  That is, I'd just normalize the strings to lower case (or uppercase, with `ucase`) and use `contains`.  You can also use `regex` with the `i` flag, but a regular expression engine seems like overkill for doing string containment.